# how to reduce duplicating codes.of ( document.getElementById().value = )

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. 
.I send request to server by calling ajax and get response 'data' as Map object.

Here's my code below.

```
success: function(data){
  document.getElementById('num').value = data.num;
  document.getElementById('product').value = data.product;
  document.getElementById('status').value = data.status;
  document.getElementById('rate').value = data.rate;
  document.getElementById('proceed_detail').value = data.proceed_detail;
  document.getElementById('schedule_detail').value = data.schedule_detail;
  document.getElementById('issues').value = data.issues;
  document.getElementById('start_date').value = data.start_date;
  document.getElementById('end_date').value = data.end_date;


}
```

As you can see, I change the value of HTML objects with given data. 
So, I call document.getElementById().value multiple times. I think it seems a little messy. So, What I want to do is to reduce the duplicating codes. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: well if you replace it with something else, you are just calling a method over and over again.....

Comment: Use a loop. And [this one weird trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on browser support, you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

`Object.keys(data)`

then loop through each key with [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

`Object.keys(data).forEach(key => document.getElementById(key).value = data[key]);`

Answer (score 1):

well you can make an array and loop...

```
['num', 'product', 'status'].forEach( function (key) {
  document.getElementById(key).value = data[key];
});
```

but what you did is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the data

```
for (var i in data) {
  document.getElementById(i).value = data[i];
}
```

```js
var data = {
  num: 1,
  product: 'Product',
  status: 'Status',
  rate: 'Rate',
  proceed_detail: 'Proceed Detail',
  schedule_detail: 'Schedule Detail',
  issues: 'Issues',
  start_date: 'Start Date',
  end_date: 'End Date'
}

for (var i in data) {
  document.getElementById(i).value = data[i];
}
```

```html
<input id='num'/>
<input id='product'/>
<input id='status'/>
<input id='rate'/>
<input id='proceed_detail'/>
<input id='schedule_detail'/>
<input id='issues'/>
<input id='start_date'/>
<input id='end_date'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without listing all the properties if you want all of them, and they all match the desired IDs.

```
success: function(data) {
  const all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (const d in data) {
    all[d].value = data[d];
  }
}
```

This may seem odd, but because `getElementsByTagName` returns a live list, and because elements are available by their ID as properties of the list, you can do this single DOM selection and use each property of `data` to get each element.

---

Here's a live demo:

```js
const data = {
  num: "foo",
  status: "bar",
  product: "rab",
  rate: "oof"
};

const all = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (const d in data) {
  all[d].value = data[d];
}
```

```html
<input id=num>
<input id=status>
<input id=product>
<input id=rate>
```

Comment: This *does* seem odd. Even if it works in a few browsers, why no just do it properly instead?

Comment: @Bergi: I'm fairly confident that it works in all browsers. Pretty sure this is very early DOM API. Anyway, just shaking things up a little. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of your elements and do a loop to add the assign the value to them. I made an example for you, since I had no accessto your "data" I muck it, you can use your own data variable as long as the properties name are similar with the elements IDs :

```
var data = {num:1,product:1,status:1,rate:1,proceed_detail:2,schedule_detail:3,issues:2,start_date:4,end_date:3}

var myElements = ['num','product','status','rate','proceed_detail','schedule_detail','issues','start_date','end_date'];

for (var i=0; i<= myElements.length -1; i++){
   document.getElementById(myElements[i]).value = data[myElements[i]];
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tfvqfarz/1/